# Emacs slime: SBCL/swank error after updating Arch linux

Tags: emacs, lisp, sbcl, slime

After updating Arch I get the following error when I try to start slime in Emacs:

```
* ; loading #P"/home/upgrd/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.24/swank-loader.lisp"
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     Symbol "%CODE-ENTRY-POINTS" not found in the SB-KERNEL package.
;   
;       Line: 1613, Column: 48, File-Position: 65201
;   
;       Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /home/upgrd/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.24/swank/sbcl.lisp" {1003FE32D3}>
;; 
;; Error compiling /home/upgrd/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.24/swank/sbcl.lisp:
;;   COMPILE-FILE returned NIL.
;; 

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004DD81F3}>:
  COMPILE-FILE returned NIL.
```

SBCL version: 2.1.1,
Slime version: 20210214.2243

Thought [this](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/470) could be the cause of the error, but imo both slime and sbcl are up to date.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I was able to start slime after downgrading sbcl to version 2.0.10. This however is obviously unsatisfactory, so help is still appreciated!